status code:400 bad request occurs, unable get error message from backend
 const downloadSif = () => {
    const apiClient = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT(params.id!));
    apiClient
      .get(true)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', fileURL);
        const dt = new Date();
        const yr = dt.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
        const mn = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const dd = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const hr = dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const min = dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const sec = dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        link.setAttribute(
          'download',
          `${'0000001145097'}${yr + mn + dd + hr + min + sec}.txt`
        );
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

        link.click();
        link.remove();
        toast.success('SIF file downloaded successfully!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error downloading SIF file:', error);
        toast.error(error?.response?.data?.validations[0]?.message);
      });
  };

in the above code i just through the error message from backend code but the validation message which i set in backend its not showing in toast message
type hereconst checkSifDownload = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req?.params?.id) {
        //Check if all the applicable employees payroll are processed
        let data = await PayrollCycleService(req.db).getPCStatusCount(
            req?.params?.id
        )
        if (data?.totalEmployee != data?.processed) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                success: false,
                message:
                    'SIF file can be downloaded once payroll processed for all the employees',
                validations: [
                    {
                        messageType: 'E',
                        message:
                            'SIF file can be downloaded once payroll processed for all the employees',
                    },
                ],
            })
        }
        next()
    }
}


it is the backend function for validation message please let me solve why the message is not showing
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

interface FetchResponses<T> {
  success: boolean;
  result: T[];
}
interface FetchResponse<T> {
  success: boolean;
  result: T;
}
export interface DeleteInterface {
  id: string;
}

export const Domain = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL;
// export const Domain = 'http://localhost:5000';

//export const Domain = 'https://821c59a989c5ecf391579ba368d601d1.serveo.net';
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${Domain}/api/v1`,
  headers: {
    ['X-TENANT-ID']: '2d703ca8-b713-4452-ae01-110e9423f0be',
  },
});

class APIClient<T> {
  endpoint: string;
  constructor(endpoint: string) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        // Add any headers you need to the config object
        config.headers['X-TENANT-ID'] = useUserStore.getState().user?.tenantId;
        config.headers['x-auth-token'] = useUserStore.getState().user?.token;

        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getAll = () => {
    return axiosInstance
      .get<FetchResponses<T>>(this.endpoint)
      .then((res) => res.data?.result || res.data);
  };

  get = (isBlob: boolean = false) => {
    return axiosInstance
      .get<FetchResponse<T> | any>(this.endpoint, {
        responseType: isBlob ? 'blob' : 'json',
      })
      .then((res) => res.data?.result || res.data);
  };

  put = (data: T) => {
    return axiosInstance.put<T>(this.endpoint, data).then((res) => res.data);
  };

  post = (data: T) => {
    return axiosInstance.post<T>(this.endpoint, data).then((res) => res.data);
  };

  remove = (id: T) => {
    return axiosInstance
      .delete<FetchResponse<T>>(this.endpoint + '/' + id)
      .then((res) => res.data.result);
  };
}

export default APIClient;


this is the function which i called in sif function from front end so what will i do to solve the issue

Does the response actually have the error message? Is the 400 status actually caused by that piece of code or from somewhere else? Did you check any of that?

no if i check the error message as error.response.status it throwing the status code 400

@gre_gor check with this

  const downloadSif = () => {
const apiClient = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT(params.id!));
apiClient
  .get()
  .then((response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = fileURL;

    const dt = new Date();
    const yr = dt.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    const mn = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const dd = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const hr = dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const min = dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const sec = dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    link.download = `${'0000001145097'}${yr}${mn}${dd}${hr}${min}${sec}.txt`;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

    toast.success('SIF file downloaded successfully!');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error downloading SIF file:', error);
    if (
      error.response &&
      error.response.data &&
      error.response.data.validations &&
      error.response.data.validations[0]
    ) {
      toast.error(error.response.data.validations[0].message);
    } else {
      toast.error('An error occurred while downloading the SIF file.');
    }
  });

};
we need to handle the blob instead of data so then we can get the error validation message from backend
